# gwt-oauth2: auth.login PopUp does not close and callback does no onSuccess

Tags: gwt, oauth-2.0

I have changed Auth using

```
xauth.setOAuthWindowUrl("https://www.mypage.com");
```

Calling

```
auth.login(req, callback)
```

After accepting the PopUp shows the "https://www.mypage.com/#access_token=....&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600" instead of being closed. The `Callback` - `onSuccess` ist not triggered.

all based on http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will follow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works not changing Auth to a different redirect like:

xauth.setOAuthWindowUrl("https://www.mypage.com");

just leave it to "https://www.mypage.com/oauthWindow.html" and the window closes correctly and the callback is working as well.